# How can I be sure I connected the electric power socket correctly?

Tags: electrical, safety

I just installed a new power socket (instead of an old one) for the first time. I plugged in a light lamp and it seemed to work OK. But the socket should be used with much heavier instruments (kitchen ovens). So, I want to make sure that it is really installed correctly, so that no accidents happen when I plug in the ovens.

Is there a safe way to check in advance that the socket is installed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are small plug-in devices with LED indicators that you plug into the socket; you can probably get one at a hardware store. The LED lights will indicate any wiring problems such as lack of ground, or confirm proper installation.

Comment: It's true that the plug-in device will detect many common miswiring problems (but not a swapped ground/neutral), it won't tell him if the outlet is safe for use with a high-current device like a plug in oven - a loose screw terminal could  show up as Ok with the outlet tester, but still be a hazard if high current causes it to heat up. I think the only way to be sure is to follow best practices when wiring the outlet -- even a resistance check may not show a fault initially, but it could get worse over time.